# sikuli performance is not fast enough

Tags: java, windows, sikuli

i writed a bot program with sikuli and working fine.
sikuli it's perfect but i can't find an way to doing reasearch image more faster.
look at this:

```
Screen s=new Screen();
  if (s.exists("c:\\example\\ex.png") != null) {s.mouseMove("c:\\example\\ex.png");}
```

this find a image, BUT it's not a very fast because the time between search image and position mouse for click (or something else) it's not immediate, take about 1 or a bit less second for position mouse.
if i need istant click and istant find image, there is a best way? (i work on windows 8.1, java 15,sikuli 2.0.4)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some guidance to increase speed for image finding:

- Settings.MoveMouseDelay=0 - this will remove default delay when moving mouse
- Decrease region size where you are searching. Now in your example you are searching whole screen
- Increase scan rate by changing Settings.ObserveScanRate. Default is 3 times per second.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you utilize the `Robot` object within Java to move the mouse and handle clicking it will function much faster.

for Example:

```
// instantiate a new Robot object

Robot robot = new Robot();

// call the method mouseMove on robot

 robot.mouseMove(xPosition, yPosition);

// click if needed at location

robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```