# SikuliX: my script reacts too slow when detecting the image, how to improve it?

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-x

I am making a script that make my character do the fishing automatically

```
fishAppear = "exclamationMark.png"
getFish = Pattern("pullBackFishRod.png").targetOffset(2,0)
Settings.MoveMouseDelay = 0
```

```
# this three lines will click on the fishButton to drop the fish road to the sea
if exists(fishButton):
    for x in range(4):
        click (fishButton)
```

After the fish rod drop to the sea, I wait for the fish to get hooked, when the fish get hooked, there will be an exclamation mark show up for about 1 second.
so I wait for the fishAppear image to show up

```
wait(fishAppear, 2 * 60)
if exists(fishAppear):
    for y in range(4):
        click(getFish)
```

The problem now is: the getFish button only show up for like 1 second after the fish get hooked.
When the script detects fishAppear, then it take some time to click on the getFish button, which the getFish button already disappeared.

How can I make the script faster but so it can search the fishAppear image faster?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65395037/1119381

Comment: See @EugeneS recommendation :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the getFish button appears on a specific region of the screen, use Region class to restrict the area of search. Sikuli will react much faster.